# C# winform creating a socket server that accept request and send response to client

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, server

I am trying to create a winform local server that accept a string from a client and then send response to client based on the string the client sends.

this is my code so far so i manage to get the "test" string from the client but when returning a response i got an error on the `AcceptCallback` function, the behavior it takes a lot of time to response and when i close the server that when it sends the "ok" message, any suggestion would be great.

error is `{"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'."}`

```
namespace ServerSocket
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static readonly int _BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[_BUFFER_SIZE];
        string text;
        Socket current;
        Socket test;
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Items.Add(text);

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupServer();
        }

        private void SetupServer()
        {
            SetText("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8999));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            SetText("Server Setup");
        }


        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in _clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            _serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = null;

            try
            {
                socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR); // problem is here
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)  
            {
                return;
            }

            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            SetText("Client connected, waiting for request...");
            test = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = 0;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                SetText("Client forcefully disconnected");
                current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
                _clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
            text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            SetText("Received Text: " + text);
            if (text.ToLower() == "test") // Client requested time
            {

                SetText("Text is a get time request");

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ok");// Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);


            }


            else
            {
                SetText("Server is sending invalid packet");
                SetText("Warning Sent");
            }
            current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), current);
        }

        private void Send_Received(string mess)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mess);
            test.Send(data);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseAllSockets();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call `Send_Received`?

Comment: What if you change the line `test = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;` to `test = socket`? Because you assume that `AR.AsyncState` is the (client)socket which is set to null => `_serverSocket.BeginAccept(...., null);`  This might not be the solution, but a potentional bugfix ;-)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen i am calling it using a send button i just tried it still no luck i will update my question, then if i change the `test = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;` to `test = socket` i got an error called `its a type but used a variable`

Comment: There's no guarantee that if a client sent `test` that you're going to *receive* `test` at the other end. You might receive `te` the first time you call `Receive` and `st` the next time. Or maybe you receive `testAndTheNextThingTheClientSent`. TCP is a *stream of bytes*, not *messages*. You do at least pay attention to `received` which many beginners fail to but you're doing more work than you need to - `GetString` can be told directly how many bytes to read from a buffer.